# JavaScript: Make a call only after a few seconds

Tags: javascript, angular, asynchronous, timeout

I am developing a web application using AngularJS (i.e. Angular 1). Although the title may seem trivial, I find myself facing a rather complicated problem (I think).
The problem is this: I have a **text input box (in a form) associated with an asynchronous service** making an HTTP call (I don't think it's important that I show the code here).
When the user types at least two characters the service **should** start only after 2000 milliseconds.

Unfortunately I was asked that if during this waiting time (2000 ms) the user still writes some other characters, the previous call (the one associated, for example, to the two characters) will no longer have to be made.
In practice, **during the 2000 ms the user must not have written anything more in the input text**, otherwise **it would have to be counted again 2000ms associated with the most recent string** to make the call. If there was another countdown in progress, it simply goes discarded and the call for that (oldest) string will simply be ignored.

I can't do this in my JavaScript code. I put here the method associated with the input text:

```
ctrl.onSearch = function(text){
        
    if (text.length >= ctrl.minLenght) { 

        $timeout(function () {
            
            // code making the call 
            
        }, 2000);

    }
}
```

`text` is the dynamic variable always associated with the text string inserted in this input field. `ctrl.minLenght` is setted to 2 and is used to not start any calls if the string entered has less than two characters.

Comment: You should check how debouncing works in JS. That will help you. There are plenty of code samples you can find on google. This is more like an open question.. like you have a problem but dont know how to solve it.. Just google it and you will find an answer IMO.

Comment: This might be helpful: [Delay code using debounce in angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32589154/delay-code-using-debounce-in-angularjs)

Comment: This is called "debouncing" (whether in JavaScript or otherwise). (The term comes from electronics, where it was necessary to handle the electric "bounce" that occurs as a pair of contacts (as in a key) come into close proximity prior to fully connecting.) Basically, start a timer for 2sec later and cancel that timer when the next key comes in before those 2sec are up.